# Linear Algebra with Block matrices in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy, linear-algebra, numpy-ndarray

I have a Linear Algebra expression as:

```
C = []
z = []

C = [[C, z], [z.T, 0]]
```

which is a simplistic way of representing `C = []`, `z = []` and `z.T` in block matrix format. The problem here is that C and z are empty matrices with undefined `numpy.shape` and will get populated in some arbitrary `while` loop following the above given line of assignment, assuming no dimensional conflicts.

Now, C and z are independent of each other so sometimes if `len(C) != 0`, `len(z) = 0` and vice versa. This leads to a very complex if-else problem such as:

```
if len(C) != 0 and len(z) != 0:
         C = np.row_stack((np.block([C, z]), np.block([np.transpose(z), 0])))
elif len(C) != 0:
```

etc. etc.
Is there a more simple way to deal with this kind of problem? I think I might have to resort to for loops to populate `C`.

Comment: Why not only deal with C and z, rendering their block-aggregated version only when strictly required ? Also, the recursive relation you exhibit  (i.e. C(C)) is not of core importance here, and creates more confusion than it helps... Looks like a [xy-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) though.

Comment: Alternative: Avoid working with lists. Zero dimensions `C = np.zeros((0,0)); z = np.zeros((0,1))` with `C = np.row_stack((np.block([C, z]), np.block([np.transpose(z), 0])))` works fine. The problem really only occurs when mixing in plains lists which lack the shape information.

Comment: @keepAlive True. I replaced the ```lists``` definition with ```array``` like so C = np.array([0]) with only 1 ```if``` statement like in the question. I only want to create the big ```C``` when there are elements in ```C``` and ```z```, which do get initialized at later in code. Thanks though!

Comment: @MikaelÖhman I actually did that including the single ```if``` statement. It works fine now. Thanks!